# check if the index of similar elements in two arrays are different

Tags: ruby

This is my first question on StackOverFlow! Please let me know if my question is not clear.

Here is what I have so far:

```
code = ["4", "4", "1", "1"]
guess = ["4", "4", "4", "1"]

@A = 0
@B = 0

code.each_with_index do |item, index|
  if item == guess[index]
    @A += 1 
  elsif code.include?(guess[index]) 
    @B += 1
  end
 print "\nA:#{@A} B:#{@B}"
end
```

I would like to increase @A by 1 if a number is in both arrays and in the same position (index).
If the number is in both arrays but in different positions (index), increase @B by 1.

I should've gotten A:3  B:0  but I am getting A:3 B:1. In the code array, there is no third "4" so B shouldn't have increased by 1.

Is it because .include? doesn't work with duplicates in arrays? How can I fix this?

Comment: Do you check only not yet iterated elements? If `code = ["1", "4"]` and `guess = ["4", "4"]` what is expected output? A: 0 B: 0 or A: 1 B: 1 or something else?

Comment: For the 3rd item, your code checks for `["4", "4", "1", "1"].include?("4"`) which returns `true` because the `code` array _does_ include `"4"`.

Comment: Classic mastermind?

Comment: @mechnicov For that example, it should be A: 1 B: 0 since "4" is in the same index in both arrays. The "1" gets no feedback (A or B score). The other "4" in the guess array is ignored unless there was another "4" in the code array. I believe this is how the game 'mastermind' works (my attempt at it at least). Thanks.

Comment: No, your question is not clear. The problem is that, "I would like to increase A by 1 if an element...` does not define "an element". If it were an element of `code` or an element of `guess`, the answer would be `A: 3, B: 1`. You say that the correct answer is `A:3, A:0`, so "an element" is something of than an element of `code` or `guess`. So what do you mean by "an element", or are pairs of elements from `code` and `guess` to be removed in the course of counting to obtain values for `A` and `B`, in which case you need to explain how that process is conducted.

Answer (score 1):

After each successful (individual) match between the code and guess, we must remove the matched elements from the equation.

For example, `code = ['1', 2']` and `guess = ['1', '1']`. We get an exact match at index 0. If we remove the matched elements:  `code = ['2']` and `guess = ['1']`, we can clearly see that there is no further match.

If we had not removed the elements, then (in addition to the exact match) index 0 of `code` would match with index 1 of `guess`... which would wrongly result in `@A = 1` and `@B = 1`. We do not want to use an already matched code element to match with a different guess element.

```
code = ["4", "4", "1", "1"]
guess = ["4", "4", "4", "1"]

unmatched_code = []
unmatched_guess = []

@A = 0
@B = 0

code.size.times do |i|
  if code[i] == guess[i]
    @A += 1
  else
    unmatched_code << code[i]
    unmatched_guess << guess[i]
  end
end

unmatched_guess.each do |g|
  matched_at_index = unmatched_code.index(g)
  if matched_at_index
    @B += 1
    unmatched_code.delete_at(matched_at_index)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
code = ["4", "4", "1", "1"]
guess = ["4", "4", "4", "1"]

visited = Array.new(guess.length) { false }

@A = 0
@B = 0

code.each_with_index do |item, index|
  if item == guess[index]
    @A += 1
    @B -= 1 if visited[index]
    visited[index] = true
  elsif guess.each_index.any? { |idx| guess[idx] == item && !visited[idx] && visited[idx] = true  }
    @B += 1
  end
end
print "\nA:#{@A} B:#{@B}"
```

Here, I am keeping track of already visited indexes in the `guess` array so that I don't count the same element in both @A and @B count.

Comment: For a guess of `["1", "4", "1", "4"]` your code returns A:2, B:1. The A-value is correct because there are 2 exact matches but the B-value should also be 2 because there are 2 partial matches: `guess[0] == code[3]` and `guess[3] == code[0]`

Answer (score 0):

You could start by combining code and guess pairs via [`zip`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/Array.html#zip-method):

```
code = ["4", "3", "1", "1"]
guess = ["2", "3", "1", "4"]

pairs = code.zip(guess)
#=> [["4", "2"], ["3", "3"], ["1", "1"], ["1", "4"]]
```

To separate the exact matches, you could use [`partition`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/Enumerable.html#partition-method):

```
exact_matches, remaining = pairs.partition { |a, b| a == b }

exact_matches
#=> [["3", "3"], ["1", "1"]]

remaining
#=> [["4", "2"], ["1", "4"]]
```

Your A-value is the number of exact matches:

```
a = exact_matches.size
#=> 2
```

And if `remaining` is [`empty?`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/Array.html#empty-3F-method), you're already done here. But it is not:

```
remaining.empty?
#=> false
```

We therefore have to determine the number of partial matches. To do so, I would start by converting the `remaining` pairs back into their respective arrays via [`transpose`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/Array.html#transpose-method):

```
code_remaining, guess_remaining = remaining.transpose

code_remaining
#=> ["4", "1"]

guess_remaining
#=> ["2", "4"]
```

Based on that arrays, you could calculate the number of their entries via [`tally`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/Enumerable.html#tally-method):

```
code_hash = code_remaining.tally
#=> {"4"=>1, "1"=>1}

guess_hash = guess_remaining.tally
#=> {"2"=>1, "4"=>1}
```

There's 1 `"4"` and 1 `"2"` in the `guess_hash`. For each of these, we can check how many are actually available in the `code_hash`:

```
code_hash["4"] #=> 1
code_hash["2"] #=> nil
```

Because `nil` means `0` here, I would use [`fetch`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/Hash.html#fetch-method) instead, which allows a default value to be passed:

```
code_hash.fetch("4", 0) #=> 1
code_hash.fetch("2", 0) #=> 0
```

And because there could be more available than guessed (or vice-versa), the actual value would be the [`min`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/Array.html#min-method)imum of them:

```
[guess_hash["4"], code_hash.fetch("4", 0)].min #=> 1
[guess_hash["2"], code_hash.fetch("2", 0)].min #=> 0
```

To get the B-value out of this, we have to [`sum`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/Enumerable.html#sum-method) the above:

```
b = guess_hash.sum { |k, v| [v, code_hash.fetch(k, 0)].min }
#=> 1
```